# How can I delete html content via javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to delete this automatically src = " " is not the link but rather it is complete

```html
<img src=" "  height="300">
The result will be like this
<img height = "300">
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it an id and do `document.getElementById("imgId").remove();`

Comment: I had it completely removed and I wanted to make it like this  <img height = "300">

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the img tag by a div element and modify his content by innerHTML

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
container.innerHTML = "";
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <img src="randomImage.jpg" a height="300">
</div>
```